# quick cocos xcode with Undefined symbols for architeture error

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

[image]

I'm sure that the framework I use and other file references are correct. Now I can't find the reason for the error. I hope everyone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

While running in Xcode simulator you got these error for Arm64 ? Then add arm64 for exclude Architecture in Xcode build settings. See attach image
[image]